# While displaying ListView, query server using item content

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Here is an issue I'm having.

I have an Activity with a ListView,

```
ArrayList<Server> serverArrayList = new ArrayList<Server>();
List<Server> serverList;
DatabaseHandler db;
ServerAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;

public void loadListView() {
    for (Server server : serverList = db.getAllServers()) {
        serverArrayList.add(server);
    };

    adapter = new ServerAdapter(this, serverArrayList);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.serverListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I need to query a server based on `server.url`,
get information, then append it to an TextViews in the row it originated from.

When should I query the server? Before setting the adapter, or after?

In addition, am I able to do this at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it both ways.

One way is to send a request to a server in your `ServerAdapter` in `getView()` method, where you have references to your textview(s)(/other views). Since server request is usually done asynchronously you will have to register a callback on receiving response that will update your row views with the information you received.

The second option is to send requests after your listview is fully ready. Again using a listener, on receipt of a response from a server you update the corresponding element of the `serverArrayList` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of the first option too, but am not sure how to do callbacks. Any tutorials or sample code you can point me to?

Comment: do I need to implement `AsyncTasksCallback` on the `MainActivity` or the `ServerAdapter`?

Comment: @NaotoIda I would recommend using some library for this purpose so that you don't have to invent your own wheel :) [here's](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) an android Volley library, very easy to use, if you expect text data from server for example - that's just what you need. In their example they send a request and then write response to textview, you can do the same in `getView()`. There's no official maven rep for Volley, you can use this [mirror](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Better you have do before setting adapter because you want to display server response in listview so better approach to set adapter after you got response from server.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll go with before!